# Page component of @shopify/polaris throws No features were provided

Tags: shopify, polaris

I'm following the Shopify tutorial to create their basic app using React.js and Node.

```
import { Layout, Page, TextStyle } from '@shopify/polaris';

const Index = () => (
  <Page>
    <Layout>
      <TextStyle variation="positive">
        Sample app using React and Next.js
      </TextStyle>
    </Layout>
  </Page>
);

export default Index;
```

As soon as I introduce the Page component, it throws the following error:
Error: No Features were provided.

Any clues as to what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you give more details about the _app.js file and its project directories?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, I fixed the issue by renaming app.js to _app.js or also could be that you have not placed _app.js in /pages directory or No wrapped the app with `<AppProvider i18n={translations}> <AppProvider/>`.

Please check out the
[using-components](http://polaris.shopify.com/components/get-started#using-components) section for instructions on wrapping application with `<AppProvider><AppProvider/>`